# Ошибка с c#, EF6 подключение к SQLite

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite, linq, sqlite3

**Здравствуйте! Как исправить ошибку?**

Вот App.config
[image: App.config]

Вот класс ApplicationContest, отвечает за подключение к бд
[image: ApplicationContest]

Вот Program.cs, где я пытаюсь найти строку, где есть строчка Nicitka
[image: Program.cs]
Ошибка в классе ApplicationContest:
[image: Ошибка]
Текст ошибки:

`System.InvalidOperationException: "The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.`

Дал максимально подробную информацию как я считаю. Если есть подсказки по коду, то пожалуйста делитесь, писал я его по документации на microsoft и уроков на ютубе.
И что вообще надо знать для удобной работы с SQLite кроме Lambda-выражений и основы LiNQ

Весь код на пастбин:

appconfig:https://pastebin.com/55Ad24h1

applicationContext: https://pastebin.com/kfV3n1M3

Program.cs: https://pastebin.com/VjVq1uhH

Comment: Выкладывайте код текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: @tym32167 прикрепил ссылки на пастбин

Comment: Вставьте код текстом в вопрос. Вопросы-картинки, и вопросы-ссылки не подходят для StackOverflow. Потому что с картинки код лень перепечатывать, а ссылка просто станет битая, и вопрос потеряет смысл.

Comment: вы сделали не то, что я вас просил. Как уже выше сказали, надо код вставлять текстом.

Comment: что касается вашего вопроса, убедитесь, что у вас подклчен нугет пакет https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite

Comment: 1. Прикрепите код в вопрос, а не на сторонний ресурс. 2. Прикрепите код текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сымитировал такую ошибку, когда удалил `System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll` из папки `References`. Видимо, вы установили не все NuGet-пакеты, необходимые для работы с SQLite.

**Необходимые NuGet-пакеты для работы с SQLite**

- System.Data.SQLite
- System.Data.SQLite.Core
- System.Data.SQLite.EF6
- System.Data.SQLite.Linq

В `App.Config` внутри `system.data:DbProviderFactories` нет тегов `remove`, это тоже вызовет ошибку. По умолчанию должно быть так

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" /> <!-- добавить -->
        <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" /> <!-- добавить -->
        <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```